# Sort nearly identical objects into lists

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

If I would have an object called `Dog` which look similar to this:

```
public class Dog {
  String type;
  String furColor;
  String country;
  String name;
}
```

And I also have an other Object looking like this:

```
public class SimilarDogs {
    ArrayList<Dog> similarDogList;
}
```

And now would I would want all dogs with the same `type`, `furColor` and `country` in the same `similarDogList` ArrayList ,but a dog can only be in one `similarDogList`. How could I accomplish that?

I thought about a double iteration trough a Dog ArrayList

1. Take first..second..third[..] Dog in array
2. Create a new similar dog list
3. iterate trough the dog list again
4. add all similar dogs to the list.

The Problem with this is, that it would create a `similarDogList` for every dog in the whole list, but I want a general one no duplicated dogs in the `similarDogList`.

---

EDIT:  I' did solve the problem like this.

```
public static ArrayList<SimilarDogs> buildDogGroups(ArrayList<Dog> dogs){
    ArrayList<SimilarDogs> similarDogGroups = new ArrayList<SimilarDogs>();

    //Generate a KeyList
    ArrayList<String> uniqueKeys = new ArrayList<>();

    for(Dog dataRecord : dogs){
        if(!uniqueKeys.contains(dataRecord.getType() + dataRecord.getFurColor() + dataRecord.getCountry())){
            uniqueKeys.add(dataRecord.getType() + dataRecord.getFurColor() + dataRecord.getCountry()); 
        }
    }

    //Generate SimilarDogGroups
    for(String uniKey : uniqueKeys){
        SimilarDogs smlDog = new SimilarDogs();
        ArrayList<Dog> similarDogRecords = new ArrayList<Dog>();
            for(DataRecord dataRecord : dogs){
                if(uniKey.equals(dataRecord.getType() + dataRecord.getFurColor() + dataRecord.getCountry())){
                    similarDogRecords.add(dataRecord);

                }
            }
            smlDog.setSameJobGroup(similarDogRecords);
        similarDogGroups.add(smlDog);
    }

    return similarDogGroups;
}
```

Comment: Sorting and Categorization are two different things, can you clarify exactly what you want.

Comment: @QuakeCore I would define it as  Categorization,   In my main programm i have Like 3 Cityes [Level One]  and  0-999 Houses [Level Two] and Like 800 People [Level Thre]   At the moment i have only the deatails about the people and every pearson has a preffered housetype and a preffered city, so i have to put each one in the right house and when the house is full i have to build a new house so in the end a person cannot be assigned to two houses and thats what a double itteration would do. I hope i could explain it a bit clearer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a multimap (`Map` of `List`s) holding a list of `Dog`s for each "category" of dogs. You will need to assign a "representant" to each category of similar dogs:

#### Solution 1

- Create class `DogCategory` that has all the properties that define it (i.e. `type`, `furColor`, `country`)

  - this one needs an override of `equals()` and `hashCode()`, making instances equal if all attributes are equal
- Create a method that assigns a `DogCategory` to each `Dog`

  - this could be a method of `Dog`: `public DogCateogry getCategory() { ... }`
- Create a `Map<DogCategory, List<Dog>>` to store the dogs in their respective categories
- For each dog, get his `DogCategory`, query the map for the appropriate list and add the dog to the list

---

#### Solution 2

- Create a `Comparator<Dog>` that returns `0` if and only if the two given `Dog`s have the relevant attributes (i.e. `type`, `furColor`, `country`) equal (the `name` can be anything)
- Use a map that takes a `Comparator` as it's sorting / equality definition

  - `TreeMap` is one such map implementation, so you could do use
    `TreeMap<Dog, List<Dog>>`
- For each dog, query the map for the appropriate list and add the dog to the list

---

#### Solution 3

- Create `DogCategory` as in solution 1
- Refactor your `Dog` to have `DogCategory dogCategory` and `String name` isntead of all the attributes
- Create a `Map<DogCategory, List<Dog>>` and use it as in solution 1

- this may or may not be appropriate refactoring, you need to decide based on your actual situation and domain model.

Answer (score 1):

> High level overview, Using HashSet remove duplication. to remove
>   duplication on our custom class(here, Dog), there must be required to
>   override, hashcode() & equals() for remove duplication.

**You can try somewhat likewise,**

```
class Dog {

    String type;
    String furColor;
    String country;
    String name;

    Dog(String type, String furColor, String country, String name){
        this.type = type;
        this.furColor = furColor;
        this.country = country;
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        if(name != null){
            return name.length();
        }
        return super.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        Dog d = (Dog)obj;
        if(d.name.equals(this.name)){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.type + " :" + this.furColor + " :" +this.country + " :" +this.name;
    }

}

public class SetExample {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        HashSet<Dog> similarDogList = new HashSet<Dog>();
        similarDogList.add(new Dog("A", "Red", "USA", "ABC"));
        similarDogList.add(new Dog("A", "Red", "USA", "XYZ"));
        similarDogList.add(new Dog("A", "Red", "USA", "PQR"));
        similarDogList.add(new Dog("A", "Red", "USA", "ABC"));

        for(Dog d : similarDogList){
            System.out.println(d);
        }

    }

}
```

**Output :**

```
A :Red :USA :PQR
A :Red :USA :XYZ
A :Red :USA :ABC
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so if I read your question correctly, you want to have lists for dogs that share type, fur color and country? Meaning in each list, all dogs have the same type, fur color and country *but* potentially different names.

You can create a Map from String to ArrayList. As those 3 properties that should be equal for all dogs are already strings, you can use them to generate map keys. Now you just need to compute the key for each dog in order to find the correct list.

Algorithm:

```
for(Dog dog : dogs) {
   String key = dog.type + dog.furColor + dog.country;
   ArrayList<Dog> dogList = map.get(key);
   if(dogList == null) {
      dogList = new ArrayList<Dog>();
      map.put(key, dogList);     
   }
   dogList.add(dog);
}
```

EDIT: As pointed out in the comments, a trivial *key generation* approach like concatenating the strings does not always work out, so you better go with the more clean approach of using Comparators.

Comment: if you're interested in further discussion we can use [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96688/discussion-between-jiri-tousek-and-user3363866). I deleted my previous comments as they're obsolete now.